# Contact Form from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, forms, asihttprequest

I want to have a contact form from my iPhone app. I have a contact.php script on the server and i need to pass the data from my app to the server. I was told about using the ASIHTTPRequest framework but i need help with the code sending the value of the UITextField to the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured it out. I ted the ASIHTTPRequest framework for the connection to my web server and called a sendForm action

```
-(IBAction)sendForm:(id)sender {

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/mail.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:[name text] forKey:@"name"];
[request setPostValue:[email text] forKey:@"email"];

 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request startSynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
ASIHTTPRequest *_request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[_request setDelegate:self];
[_request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[textField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[_request appendPostData:data];
[_request start];
[data release];
```

Delegate of ASIHTTPRequest

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

Comment: can i just use the nsurl to post the data from my textfields to the web url?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer and example from a previous SO Post. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923868/how-to-implement-login-functionality-to-native-iphone-app/10923919#comment14248980_10923919)

This describes using `ASIHTTPRequest` framework to `POST` variables to a Server side script.

Hope this helps!