# How to call a function of web service for login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a Web-Service API in PHP and i want to do login using this api in my ios application.

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') 
{ 
// Get tag
 $tag = $_POST['tag'];
 // Include Database handler 
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
 $db = new DB_Functions(); 
// response Array 
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0); // check for tag type 
if ($tag == 'login')
 { 
// Request type is check Login 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; // check for user 
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

 if ($user != false)
 {
 // user found // echo json with success = 1 
$response["success"] = 1; 
$response["user"]["fname"] = $user["firstname"]; 
$response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lastname"]; 
$response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
 $response["user"]["uname"] = $user["username"];
 $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
 $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"]; 
echo json_encode($response);
 }
 else 
{
 // user not found
 // echo json with error = 1 
$response["error"] = 1; 
$response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!"; 
echo json_encode($response);
 } 
}
else 
{ 
echo "Digitalnet API";
 }
```

This Web-Service checks for the database query to match the email and password.

Now I have made the connection with the web service and it is returning me the response Digitalnet Api.

In the button event

```
- (IBAction)btnSignIn:(id)sender {

if( ([txtUserEmail.text isEqualToString:@""]) || ([txtUserPassword.text isEqualToString:@""]))
{ 
[self showErrorAlert];
 }

NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email==%@ AND password==%@",self.txtUserEmail.text,self.txtUserPassword.text];
 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/ColorPicker/index.php"]; NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;
 NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"Login response: is %@",str); //getting response
else if(str != nil)
{
 ColorPickerViewController *cpvc =[[ColorPickerViewController alloc] init]; 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:cpvc animated:YES];
 }
else
  {   NSLog(@"some thing went wrong");
   }
 }
```

What should I do to make login with this web-service so that the request is being sent from the application on button click, and the Api Validates the Request's with email and password and then after the user is authenticated it will allowed to move to the next screen/view.

NOTE: The Api is included with the class 'include/DB_Functions.php' which will check the user validation with mysql db so please don't be confused with the Web-Service I just need to know the logic on IPHONE.

Comment: `htt://localhost`? Your idevice is highly unlikely to be running its own webserver...

Comment: yes i think it is not the problem... it is giving the response

Comment: @MarcB please help me to sort this out am a newbie...

Comment: I don't see what the question is. You're sending a request and getting the response. What isn't working the way you intend it to?

Comment: Why are you posting your question from a different account? And is this a PHP question or an iOS question?

Comment: need to make a login with this api...like if email and password in the app matches the email and password in web-service then the user is allowed to proceed\

Comment: and for sure this is a ios question... i have give the php code so that the other people who view the question can see the web-service i am calling

Comment: Can any one suggest me tutorial for calling web service using function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say, you are getting response from web- service. That means it is working fine.
I think there is some problem sending post parameters from url to the web-service.

Try something like this(just a piece of code. you need to modify it accordingly):

```
NSString * parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",self.txtUserEmail.text,self.txtUserPassword.text];
[_mutableRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[parameters UTF8String] length:[parameters length]];
[_mutableRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];
```

// then hit the connection using `NSURLConnection`

Comment: Puneet bhai i have added a nsstring *tag = login